# Django-ratings - 404 error "Invalid model or app_label"? Why?

Tags: django, raty, django-ratings

Can someone help me with Django-ratings app? I'm trying to post a rating but the app doesn't seem to do anything. What part am I missing here? Really hard to find examples out there..

My function looks like this (jquery Raty plugin):

```
$('.raty').raty({
  click: function(score, evt) {
  var vote_url = "/rate/" + $(this).attr('value') + "/" + score + "/" ;

    $.ajax({
      url: vote_url,
      type: "GET",
      success: function(){
        alert('Vote successful!');
      }
});
   }
});
```

The GET seems to work but i can see in my admin that no votes/scores are registered.

In my URL:

```
url(r'rate/(?P<object_id>\d+)/(?P<score>\d+)/', AddRatingFromModel(), {
    'app_label': 'myapp',
    'model': 'MyModel',
    'field_name': 'rating',
}),
```

EDIT:

I'm getting a 404 error "Invalid model or app_label". But I'm pretty sure thoose are the correct ones.

Comment: Could you show `AddRatingFromModel`?

Comment: sneawo, It's just a view that is part of the original package. I don't think i should have to change something there. But i guess i could post it if you think it helps?

Im trying to follow this:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-ratings

Comment: i think it's in here: https://github.com/dcramer/django-ratings

Comment: What does your ajax response returns? You can see this in Chrome Developer Tools > Network, etc.

Comment: Andrey, oh nice I didn't know about that. It says in status/text: 403
FORBIDDEN. Is that a CSRF related problem? I'm still quite new to all this. Not even sure if "post" is the method type i should use here..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This applications does not need the `POST` request. The easiest way to solve the problem is to set 'GET' method in ajax request

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    type: 'GET'
    ...
```

To avoid `404` you need to  write model name in lowercase. In `django.contrib.contenttypes` `app_label` and `model` use lowercase.

```
url(r'rate/(?P<object_id>\d+)/(?P<score>\d+)/', AddRatingFromModel(), {
...
  'model': 'mymodel',
...
}),
```

Comment: Thanks! I've managed to get pass the 403-forbidden with post+csrf token and also by changing to GET (don't need csrf token on that right?). But instead of 403 i get the 404 returned now: "Invalid `model` or `app_label`." I cant understand why. I'm getting so tired with this. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: @user3199840 show your models.py of your app. Does folder contain `__init__.py`, have you added your `app` to `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: Yes both "myapp" and the "djangoratings" app are listed in the settings "installed apps". "myapp" does have an __init__.py in it's folder. They both appear in the admin. And in my models i have a class named "MyModel" with a rating-field. I'm following this: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-ratings .I'll edit the post with my model.

Comment: OMG! I think it works!! Such a simple thing but i think i never would have found it on my own. Really cool of you taking your time to help me out! Thanks a lot man!!!